# Composer dump-autoload or update results in fatal error on Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

Just tried to run a `composer dump-autoload`, but ended up with the following error, which I have never had previously

```
Class UpdateHelper\ComposerPlugin contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Composer\Plugin\PluginInterface::deactivate, Composer\Plugin\PluginInterface::uninstall) in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/vendor/kylekatarnls/update-helper/src/UpdateHelper/ComposerPlugin.php on line 11
```

Searched on G to find some answers, but found nothing even remotely close the problem I am having here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I just found a solution to this problem. Here it is for those who have the same problem.

I have had to delete the directory `kylekatarnls` located inside my `vendor` directory then run `composer update --prefer-source` and after that `composer dump-autoload`.

Now all is working just fine.

Comment: In my case `composer update -- prefer-source` make `kylekatarnls` again and problem is exist. Therefore after removing `kylekatarnls` just run `composer dump-autoload` is enough.

Comment: this is really helpful after many hours of search.

Comment: For me, original answer worked. I was running `composer require <package>`

Answer (score 13):

It seems like you're using Composer v2. If so, read on...

Composer v2 [adds some new functions](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/3fc9ede24b85cbca0914060e6043abdc2cb1e406#diff-9761e5e6cef580d24c5a05d870dcc479) to their Plugin interface (namely `deactivate()` and `uninstall()`)

However `kylekatarnls/update-helper` < v1.2.1 is implementing said interface but **does not implement the new functions**.

So to fix, you'll need to update `kylekatarnls/update-helper` to the latest (v1.2.1 at time of writing), which contains [a fix](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/update-helper/releases/tag/1.2.1) (implements the missing methods):

```
composer update kylekatarnls/update-helper
```

Comment: The issue: https://github.com/kylekatarnls/update-helper/issues/7

Answer (score 7):

I remove the vendor directory and the composer.lock file. After execute composer install and all works well.

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade Composer to version 1 worked for me.

```
composer self-update 1.10.22
rm -rf vendor
composer install
```

Comment: This was the only answer that worked without having to use `composer update` or remove composer.lock. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Please **delete or change name** the directory "***kylekatarnls***" and **composer update**

1, `mv kylekatarnls kylekatarnls_bk` or `rm -rf kylekatarnls`

2, `composer update`

**=> Success**

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
rm -rf vendor
rm -f composer.lock
composer install
```